# Stack overflow with Fibonacci's recursive call

Tags: java, stack, fibonacci

How exactly is the Java stack set up?

For university, I shall determine what the biggest possible [Fibonacci number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) that is calculated by a recursive method and can be handled by the stack.

The interesting thing is: Tests showed that it doesn't matter how much `-Xmx` and `-Xms` the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) has. I am able to run up to Fib(4438). But the results aren't consistent. Somtimes it goes down to 4436.

Is there formular for the stack?

Any increase of the stack via `-Xss 4096m` doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Stack size increase is done with -Xss command, like this, for 1MB stack size: -Xss1m

Comment: Your host computer could be running more or less programs in memory at any specific point. You shouldnt expect that the memory available to your program will always be constant.

Comment: @Tejs: Actually you would suspect that you have a constant stack size and if this interferes with other program's memory requirements, that paging is used to create the illusion for every program that it has as much memory as necessary. In so far I can understand OP's doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Xmx and -Xms sets memory accessible for JVM **heap**, you need to increase **stack** size, you do this with the help of -Xss option.

Comment: Hm, so if you don't supply this argument, how is the stack size determined?

Comment: It has preset default value. Depending on operating system and JVM version and JVM creator (Oracle, IBM, etc) it varies from 256MB to 2048MB

Answer (score 3):

You've misinterpreted the assignment. Stack size matters very little. The problem is exponential. And you cannot possibly have gotten to Fib(4438) with the naive recursive program. Using the following code, you'll be lucky if you make it to Fib(50):

```
public static BigInteger f(int n) {
    if (n == 0) 
        return BigInteger.ZERO; 
    if (n == 1) 
        return BigInteger.ONE; 
    return f(n-1).add(f(n-2));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

[*Java. How to program*, 9th edition, Deitel and Deitel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057E40I2), page 771:

```
 // Fig. 18.5: FibonacciCalculator.java
 // Recursive Fibonacci method.
 import java.math.BigInteger;
 public class FibonacciCalculator
 {
     private static BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf( 2 );


     // Recursive declaration of method fibonacci
     public static BigInteger fibonacci( BigInteger number )
     {
         if ( number.equals( BigInteger.ZERO ) ||
              number.equals( BigInteger.ONE ) ) // Base cases
             return number;
         else // Recursion step
             return fibonacci( number.subtract( BigInteger.ONE ) ).add(
         fibonacci( number.subtract( TWO ) ) );
     } // end method fibonacci


     // Displays the Fibonacci values from 0-40
     public static void main( String[] args )
     {
         for ( int counter = 0; counter <= 40; counter++ )
             System.out.printf( "Fibonacci of %d is: %d\n", counter,
         fibonacci( BigInteger.valueOf(counter)));
     } // End main()

 } // end class FibonacciCalculator
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, which is how deep the recursion can be made to go.

Comment: Is just a reference, the chapter is all the answer for OP's question.This is just the code.